# How to split a data if the delimiter to use is present on the data itself? E.G, data is Nov, 2023. Dec 2023, How can I split the two date?

Tags: function, date, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula

Here is the sample data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VQLSy7graqSDlk1K8M_ydzyIP6EJATF6AtmGdFLDHWs/edit#gid=0

I need to split the dates on the cell to collect all the requested date, the output from the google form shows like this > November 1, 2023, December 25, 2023, January 4, 2024. How can I split the dates if they are on a single cell and the supposed comma to be used as delimiter is also present on the date? I tried using split then concatenate but it's a lot of work, I hope that there is an easier way for this

I tried using Find Len syntax but it's only helpful on 2 date request, but the maximum date that can be requested on the form is 6.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use a different delimiter, or don't include a comma in the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX to identify the pattern.
The below formula identifies the year as a 4-digit number, appends the year with "|"(new delimiter), and finally splits the data

```
=split(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\d{4}),", "$1|"), "|")
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! This is a lifesaver